# Inner Join sqlite from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Follow code is giving me an ambiguous column DRIVER.driv_id error, any help?

```
SELECT DRIVER.driv_id, DRIVER.firstName, DRIVER.surName, DRIVER.nationality,   TEAMSTANDING.teamName, RESULTS.points
FROM TEAMSTANDING INNER JOIN DRIVER ON TEAMSTANDING.driv_id=DRIVER.driv_id,
RESULTS INNER JOIN DRIVER ON RESULTS.driv_id=DRIVER.drv_id
WHERE TEAMSTANDING.comp_id=2
GROUP BY DRIVER.driv_id;
```

Comment: In addition to my answer below, I'm not sure if your query does what you think it does.  You have that , after the first inner join which means you're doing a CROSS JOIN on RESULTS.

Answer (score 8):

You must try this you add driver table multiple times so that this is created

```
SELECT 
    DRIVER.driv_id, DRIVER.firstName, DRIVER.surName, DRIVER.nationality,   TEAMSTANDING.teamName, RESULTS.points   
FROM 
    TEAMSTANDING
    INNER JOIN 
        DRIVER
ON 
        TEAMSTANDING.driv_id=DRIVER.driv_id
    INNER JOIN 
        RESULTS 
    ON 
        RESULTS.driv_id=DRIVER.drv_id
WHERE 
    TEAMSTANDING.comp_id=2
GROUP BY 
    DRIVER.driv_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got DRIVER joined to twice in your query, so you have two tables aliased as DRIVER and you use driv_id from both.

Either alias the other table as something else or, if it's not needed, drop it from the JOIN.

Comment: I will put something up on sqlfiddle in a little while.  Can't just now.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7477e/6 This is the query I think you were trying to write.  Below it is your FROM statement for comparison.